# How to exclude a string from my RegEx in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

please excuse my title. Didn't know a better one. 
My problem. I have to find words. This words can have square brackets / parentheses around them or be in quotation marks. To find all words I use:

```
new RegEx('\\b' + arrWord + '\\b', 'g');
```

Now the problem. Some words have for example ["DN"]word or ...ignore">,... in front of them. This words I don't want to find. I read something about RegEx exclude a string, but I can't get it to work. Does someone have an idea or can help? 
Or is it not possible to do something like that with RegEx in Javascript?

Comment: `["DN"]word or ...ignore">,... ` cant tell what is what here.

Comment: What array referes to this `arrWord`, yes aray ?

Comment: What are boundrys for `\b` ?

Comment: @Edward the arrWord is from an array of words. I iterate over the array and arrWord is the current word. The \b is needed because I want to match only foo as a word and not also foobar. And the words can have square brackets / parentheses, but I don't want to match this, only the words and it works fine with \b. The only missing thing was "(?<!" what mhSangar posted in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was kind of tricky because `["DN"]` matches with "surrounded by quotations", so the final regex is a bit long. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/0mga6S/2) you have it with some examples, and the regex itself is:

```regex
(?<!\[\"DN\"\])(?<!\.\.\.ignore)(\[\w+\]|\(\w+\)|(\"\w+\")(?=(?<!\"DN\")))
```

Here you can see how it is composed:

- `(?<!\[\"DN\"\])` asserts that the following string does not match `["DN"]`.
- `(?<!\.\.\.ignore)` asserts that the following string does not match `...ignore`.
- `(\[\w+\]|\(\w+\)|(\"\w+\")(?=(?<!\"DN\")))` is composed by 3 OR conditions:

  - `\[\w+\]` matches if word is surrounded by brackets.
  - `\(\w+\)`matches if word is surrounded by parenthesis.
  - `(\"\w+\")(?=(?<!\"DN\"))` matches if word surrounded by quotations and is not `"DN"`.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @mhSangar, the missing thing was "(?<!".

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to do what's called in REGEX "negative lookahead":

```
\bword\b(?!...ignore)
```